# Sending status data via JSON response to POST - parse via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, dropzone.js

I have a PHP code for uploading files, which works fine, and as final outcome I have sent JSON response with uploading status which I'm not able to retrieve.

After uploading file (POST) my response looks like:

```
{"html_content":"<p>File was uploaded<\/p>"}
```

PHP uploader code looks like:

```
if (!is_file($targetFile)) {
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    $html_content="<p>File was uploaded</p>";
}
else {
    $html_content="<p>You have uploaded duplicate.</p>";
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);  
}

$json_array=array('html_content'=>$html_content);

header('Content-type: text/json');
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json_array);
```

and JavaScript main code to get message displayed:

```
this.on("success", function(file,responseText) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {

             var htmlElement = document.createElement("div");
             htmlElement.setAttribute("class","success-message");
             var responseText = response.html_content;
             var messageText = document.createTextNode(responseText);
             htmlElement.appendChild(messageText);
             file.previewTemplate.appendChild(htmlElement);

             console.log(response.html_content);
        }
    });
});
```

When I will unwrap above JS from AJAX part and set variable `responseText` as a static all works fine.

Also when I will not use AJAX and just output `console.log(responseText);` I'm getting this in the console:

`Object {html_content: "<p>File was uploaded</p>"}`

Any clue what I have missed in my case?

Comment: I wonder if defining Content-type header twice in php causes browser failure to parse the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it solved. JavaScript code looks like

```
        this.on("success", function(file,responseText) {

            str = JSON.stringify(responseText);
            responseMessage = $.parseJSON(str);

            var htmlElement = document.createElement("div");
            htmlElement.setAttribute("class","success-message");
            htmlElement.innerHTML = responseMessage.html_content;
            file.previewTemplate.appendChild(htmlElement);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending a request to your PHP server. Specify URL argument.

```
 $.ajax({url: "your_php_file",
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function (response) {
                   ...
                }
            });
```

Or even better:

```
$.getJSON( "your_php_file", function( data ) { ... });
```

Comment: I have already done that but `response.html_content` is parsed as `undefined`. I thought it was because `your_php_file` was already executed during file uploading (and JSON generated at that time too)

Comment: My guess is that your PHP breaks somewhere before sending the JSON. Try removing the upload logic, and just returning JSON from PHP first.

Comment: As I have mentioned in the OP - PHP uploader code works fine. I'm able to upload files and generate JSON as response to each uploaded file but JavaScript part is not getting correct data. IMO I shouldn't checking `your_php_file` with JS as was already executed and returned JSON back to browser but simple get those returned data. Calling `your_php_file` directly will not return anything as at that point file wasn't uploaded.

Comment: Side note - my JSON response is to POST (file uploading)

Comment: Now I understand what you tried to do, and yes, PHP script results are not persisted, so you need to check it in your POST request.